# Extracting information from input list of strings by using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have following list of inputs which I want to extract name, symbol, value and unit and output as dictionary.

Example,
Input:

```
x = ['abc >123%', 'Abc5d 12.3%', 'Hz-xyz = 321k/mL', 'N+ 456', '789 mm/min/1.3', '<=55']
```

Expected output:

```
out = {
        'x1':{
                'name':'abc', 
                'symbol': '>', 
                'value': '123', 
                'unit': '%'
             },
        'x2':{
                'name':'Abc5d', 
                'symbol': None, 
                'value': '12.3', 
                'unit': '%'
              },
        'x3':{
                'name':'Hz-xyz', 
                'symbol':'=', 
                'value': '321', 
                'unit': 'k/mL'
              },
         'x4':{
                 'name':'N+',
                 'symbol': None,
                 'value': '456',
                 'unit': None
               },
         'x5':{
                 'name': None,
                 'symbol': None,
                 'value': '789',
                 'unit': 'mm/min/1.3'
               },
          'x6':{
                 'name': None,
                 'symbol': '<=',
                 'value': '55',
                 'unit': None
                }
      }
```

I use the following line of codes, but the output isn't same as expected output.

```
def extract_info(x):
   out = {}
   pattern = r'([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\s*([><=]{0,2})\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([A-Za-z/%]+)?'

   for i, string in enumerate(x, start=1):
       match = re.match(pattern, string)
       name, symbol, value, unit = match.groups() if match else (None, None, None, None)
       out[f'x{i}'] = {'name': name, 'symbol': symbol, 'value': value, 'unit': unit}

   return out
```

Can someone suggest how to write regular expression correctly to get expected output from the input list in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell the best way. Usually it's not what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that of the four parts: name, symbol, value, and unit; only the value is mandatory, other parts are optional. Plus, the blank spaces can be in between the parts. This means the regular expression can be complex. The best way to deal with complex regular expression is to compile it using the `re.VERBOSE` flag. This flag allows for extra white space and comment within the expression, making it easier to understand.

```py
import re
import pprint

x = ["abc >123%", "Abc5d 12.3%", "Hz-xyz = 321k/mL", "N+ 456", "789 mm/min/1.3", "<=55"]

pattern = re.compile(
    r"""
# Optional spaces
\s*

# Name: optional, starts with a letter and does not contain symbols or spaces
(?P<name>[a-zA-z]+[^><= ]*){0,1}

\s*

# Symbol: optional, any relational symbol
(?P<symbol>[><=]*){0,1}

\s*

# Value: decimal, including the dot
(?P<value>[0-9\.]+)

\s*

# Unit: optional, anything after the value
(?P<unit>.*){0,1}
\s*
""",
    re.VERBOSE,
)
out = {}
for i, text in enumerate(x, 1):
    key = f"x{i}"
    matched = pattern.match(text)
    if matched:
        value = {k: v or None for k, v in matched.groupdict().items()}
        out[key] = value
    else:
        out[key] = None

pprint.pprint(out)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'x1': {'name': 'abc', 'symbol': '>', 'unit': '%', 'value': '123'},
 'x2': {'name': 'Abc5d', 'symbol': None, 'unit': '%', 'value': '12.3'},
 'x3': {'name': 'Hz-xyz', 'symbol': '=', 'unit': 'k/mL', 'value': '321'},
 'x4': {'name': 'N+', 'symbol': None, 'unit': None, 'value': '456'},
 'x5': {'name': None, 'symbol': None, 'unit': 'mm/min/1.3', 'value': '789'},
 'x6': {'name': None, 'symbol': '<=', 'unit': None, 'value': '55'}}
```

#### Notes

- The `(?P<symbol>...)` expression gives this segment a name: "symbol". This name is a key in a dictionary returned by `groupdict()`
- The `{0,1}` says this segment could happens 0 or 1 time. In other word, it happens at most 1 time.
- Because we use the `re.VERBOSE` flag to compile the regular expression, we are free to add blank lines and white spaces to the expression. They are ignored.
- The `{k: v or None for k, v in matched.groupdict().items()}` code segment turns any empty string "" into `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

def extract_info(x):
    out = {}
    pattern = r'([A-Za-z0-9-+]*)\s*([><=]*)\s*([0-9.]*)\s*(.*)'

    for i, string in enumerate(x, start=1):
        match = re.match(pattern, string)
        name, symbol, value, unit = match.groups() if match else (None, None, None, None)        
        name = name if name else None
        symbol = symbol if symbol else None
        out[f'x{i}'] = {'name': name, 'symbol': symbol, 'value': value, 'unit': unit}
    return out

output = extract_info(['abc >123%', 'Abc5d 12.3%', 'Hz-xyz = 321k/mL', 'N+ 456', '789 mm/min/1.3', '<=55'])
pprint(output)
```

Output:

```
{'x1': {'name': 'abc', 'symbol': '>', 'unit': '%', 'value': '123'},
 'x2': {'name': 'Abc5d', 'symbol': None, 'unit': '%', 'value': '12.3'},
 'x3': {'name': 'Hz-xyz', 'symbol': '=', 'unit': 'k/mL', 'value': '321'},
 'x4': {'name': 'N+', 'symbol': None, 'unit': '', 'value': '456'},
 'x5': {'name': '789', 'symbol': None, 'unit': 'mm/min/1.3', 'value': ''},
 'x6': {'name': None, 'symbol': '<=', 'unit': '', 'value': '55'}}
```

Comment: x5 and x6 outputs are different from expected output. So, the suggested solution give wrong output.

Comment: Ok @Peter sorry, had to make a few changes lol, try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def extract_info(x):
  out = {}
  pattern =r'([a-zA-z]+[^><= ]*){0,1}\s*([><=]*){0,1}\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*(.*){0,1}\s*'
  for i, string in enumerate(x, start=1):
    match = re.match(pattern, string)
    groups = match.groups() if match else (None, None, None, None)
    # print(groups)
    name, symbol, value, unit = [group if group and group.strip() != '' else None for group in groups]

    out[f'x{i}'] = {'name': name, 'symbol': symbol, 'value': value, 'unit': unit}

  return out


#input 
x = ['abc >123%', 'Abc5d 12.3%', 'Hz-xyz = 321k/mL', 'N+ 456', '789 mm/min/1.3', '<=55']

print(extract_info(x))
```

Output

```
{
'x1': {'name': 'abc', 'symbol': '>', 'value': '123', 'unit': '%'}, 
'x2': {'name': 'Abc5d', 'symbol': None, 'value': '12.3', 'unit': '%'}, 
'x3': {'name': 'Hz-xyz', 'symbol': '=', 'value': '321', 'unit': 'k/mL'}, 
'x4': {'name': 'N+', 'symbol': None, 'value': '456', 'unit': None}, 
'x5': {'name': None, 'symbol': None, 'value': '789', 'unit': 'mm/min/1.3'},
'x6': {'name': None, 'symbol': '<=', 'value': '55', 'unit': None}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will push all the fields in the correct matching position.

```
import re
re.findall(r"'([^\s']*?)\s*([<>=]*)\s*((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)?)\s*([^\s']*)'", r"x = ['abc >123%', 'Abc5d 12.3%', 'Hz-xyz = 321k/mL', 'N+ 456', '789 mm/min/1.3', '<=55']")
```

Output

```
[('abc', '>', '123', '%'), ('Abc5d', '', '12.3', '%'), ('Hz-xyz', '=', '321', 'k/mL'), ('N+', '', '456', ''), ('', '', '789', 'mm/min/1.3'), ('', '<=', '55', '')]
```

Regex layout

```
'
# name
( [^\s']*? )                  # (1)
\s* 
# symbol
( [<>=]* )                    # (2)
\s* 
# value
(                             # (3 start)
   (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
    | \. \d+ 
   )?
)                             # (3 end)
# unit
\s* 
( [^\s']* )                   # (4)
'
```